# How to conduct an NDVI and regression with ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, ndvi

I would ideally like to execute an NDVI on a sample of NAIP images and then use the NDVI scores per district or whatever my aggregate zone is, probably census tract.  My goal is to identify census tract parcels which are good for development based on, my NDVI score, and other socio-economic demographics such as age, population, income, businesses, etc.  I know NDVI can be calcuated in ArcMap, how would I translate the values that I receive per pixel to a vector data set?

Comment: I think you're question needs a bit of clarification.  Are you asking how to perform an NDVI in ArcMap?  How to perform a regression analysis?  Or how to convert the NDVI raster to a vector dataset?  If the latter, to polygon or point data?

Comment: I am asking how to convert raster to vector data to be joined to another polygon, while maintaining my NDVI values.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to do is use Zonal Statistics.  If you have the [**Spatial Analyst Extension**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Spatial_Analyst_toolbox/009z00000003000000/), you can perform [**Zonal Statistics**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Zonal_Statistics/009z000000w7000000/) or [**Zonal Statistics as Table**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Zonal_Statistics_as_Table/009z000000w8000000/).

Your input raster would be your NDVI.  Your polygon layer would be your districts or census tract parcels.  With Zonal Statistics, you can get the average NDVI, the maximum, minimum, etc.

Here's the overview of all [**zonal tools**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Zonal_tools/009z000000w1000000/).

If you're wanting to convert your NDVI raster to polygons, you can use the **[Raster to Polygon](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Raster_to_Polygon/001200000008000000/)** tool.  Though, you may want to **[reclassify](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Reclassify/009z000000sr000000/)** it first.  But again, you'll need the Spatial Analyst Extension for that.